# Sandcastle Generate Code Block

Tags: sandcastle, shfb

I've a C# project that I need to create documentation file. I'm using last version of SHFB and VS 2005 to create XML documentation file.

How can I add code blocks inside documentation? I wanna show all lines of my function, not only one part for sample.

I found a document that describes how to add code block in sandcastle with code tag, but my functions dont have that tag, also in project there are a lot of functions, so its imposible to add tags for all functions.

Is there any way to build code tag from project automaticly, or a plugin for show inside of function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the source and region custom attributes on a  element in each function's XML comments.  There's no way to just import code based on an API member ID so if you really want all the code from every property, event, method etc. in your help file, you're going to have to do it the hard way: Wrap the body of each in a region and add a  element to the comments of each one to import that region.

As requested by e-mail I'm posting this here but please note that I do not follow StackOverflow.  If you have questions regarding SHFB or Sandcastle, post them on the SHFB project's discussion page on CodePlex.  Thanks.

Eric